# Injecting HTML to a DOM element with chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to figure out the best way to inject a full HTML page into an already existing page via a chrome extension. The problem is say I am browsing page A and want to load the facebook page onto page A, is it best to place the response from the AJAX request into a div element with the `innerHTML` method or should I create a new iframe and write its document? If I do go with the second answer, would I then be bound to the iframe constraints posed by facebook or other sites that don't allow iframe loading?

Comment: And what will you do with conflicting CSS and element IDs in the first case? Shadow DOM?

Comment: Great point, any disadvantages to shadow DOM? chrome has supported it for quite some time now, so I don't think compatibility is an issue.